# v-select set number of items shown in dropdown Vuetify

Tags: vuetify.js, v-select

I have the following v-select:

[image: Weekday v-select]

It has 7 items (for each weekday) but I want it to show all 7 when it's opened, not only the first 6 with a scrollbar. I can't seem to find an v-select API option for that.
I searched on the Vuetify page and on several StackOverflow questions.

How can I do that and if I missed something: What should I have been searching for?

Thanks!

Comment: You can pass the items with the computed weekdays (where you can all your logic you want)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unset `max-height`, so that the dialog is not limited.

It's a property on the underlying [`v-menu`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-menu/#props-max-height), you pass it using [:menu-props](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props-menu-props):

```html
<v-select
  :menu-props="{maxHeight: 'unset'}"
  ...
```

Here is a snippet (you need to expand it to see it in full height though):

```js
const {
  createApp,
  ref
} = Vue;
const {
  createVuetify
} = Vuetify
createApp({}).use(createVuetify()).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.6/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <div>
      <v-select
        label="Weekday" 
        :items="['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']"
        :menu-props="{maxHeight: 'unset'}"
      ></v-select>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.1.6/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

It should work the same using Vuetify for Vue 2, its [:menu-props](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props-menu-props) is actually documented a bit better.

Does that work for you?

Comment: It does! Thank you so much!
Why didn't I find this in the v3 documentation? Where should I have searched? https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/

Comment: Hey, that's great! Yeah, v3 documentation is still missing large chunks. Sucks particularly that `:menu-props` is not a name that gives much away. Ultimately, I looked at the [source code](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/next/packages/vuetify/src/components/VSelect/VSelect.tsx#L250) and pieced it together, which is not the best way this can go. Then I saw that v2 has props documented, so next time, I'm gonna look there. Again, not ideal, but what can you do - from what I know they are working as fast as they can to get v3 finished.

Comment: Wow, thanks for going through all that effort!
Grüße nach Leipzig aus Ulm :D